# Google Sheets Graph - How to remove vertical captions

Tags: graph, google-sheets, google-visualization

How can I remove the text that is vertically written for every bar in this google sheets graph?

[image]

This might be a stupid question but I looked everywhere and couldn't figure it out.

Thank you.

Edit: As it was asked for, here is a link to the sheet. I created a dummy version of the graph, as the original document contains sensitive information.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dm7sJNNv_1OxNSjfEd699V2mZ6Q7Plm57yqnIk7bLMc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post a link to a copy of your spreadsheet, so that we could see how it's constructed?

Comment: Looks those may be "Data Labels." @ttarchala links to documents should be discouraged in favor of context provided directly in the question - the document can change, be deleted, etc., while the question will have an accessible revision history. OP should include an example datasource layout, and perhaps a screenshot of the chart configuration options.

Comment: @tehhowch About the links, in general I agree but to be honest this question is about debugging a Google Spreadsheet, and I don't think there is a good way to serialize/share its contents other than via... Google Spreadsheet. Of course, the OP could and should improve his question, perhaps with a screenshot of the chart's underlying data, or the chart's dialog box contents etc. But in the end, there is no replacement for the actual debug environment.

Comment: it's possible this could benefit from the [#google-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-visualization) tag

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I edited the question and added a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These vertical labels are X-Axis labels, not (as suggested by the comment from @tehhowch) Data Labels. Go to the Chart Editor and turn them off here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I feel a little bit dumb now, seemed to have missed it.